# R - combining lines from multiple CSV into a data frame

Tags: r, csv

I have a folder with hundreds of CSV files each containing data for a particular postal code.

Each CSV files contains two columns and thousands of rows. Descriptors are in Column A, values are in Column B.

I need to extract two pieces of information from each file and create a new table or dataframe using the values in [Column A, Row 2] (which is the postal code) and [Column B, Row 1585] (which is the median income).

The end result should be a table/dataframe with two columns: one for postal code, the other for median income.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `read.table/read.csv` inside a `do.call` with `rbind.data.frame` passed on to get all the `csv` files within a directory. It can be done in a single line.

Comment: Further reading http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-rbinding-race-for-vs-do-call-vs-rbind-fill/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: this question is pretty vague. Next time, be sure to add a reproducible example that we can run on our machines. It will help you, the people answering your questions, and future users.

You might try something like:

```
files = list.files("~/Directory")

my_df = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = length(files)

for(i in 1:length(files)){
    row1 = read.csv("~/Directory/files[i]",nrows = 1)
    row2 = read.csv("~/Directory/files[i]", skip = 1585, nrows = 1)
    my_df = rbind(my_df, rbind(row1, row2))
}

my_df = my_df[,c("A","B")]
# Note on interpreting indexing syntax: 
  Read this as "my_df is now (=) my_df such that ([) the columns (,) 
  are only A and B (c("A", "B")) "
```

Comment: you might have meant `rbind(row1, row2)`

Comment: @Frash I meant both (though that doesn't exclude the possibility for errors); I wanted to bind the existing data frame (that I'm building) with the new rows (that also needed to be bound together).

Comment: The problem is that row 1 has only piece of information, while row 1585 has two. Your code and advice has given me a lot to work with, so I should be well on my way.

Comment: @Pubb you'll need to put something in the 2nd column of row 1 then, even if it's an NA value.

Comment: @Nancy: Can you explain what the last two assignments are doing? Thanks

Comment: @Pubb I added a comment; let me know if there's any more confusion. Also wink wink nudge nudge is this worthy of an upvote or accepted answer?

Comment: Thanks very much Nancy. As you can tell, I am new to this. I did upvote this, but apparently I don't have enough cred to change anything.

Comment: @Nancy I meant `cbind(row1, row2)`, which will work for when you have more than 1 row to bind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.files` function to get directories for all your files and then use `read.csv` and `rbind` in `for` loop to create one `data.frame`.

Something like this:

```
direct<-list.files("directory_to_your_files")
df<-NULL
for(i in length(direct)){
  df<-rbind(df,read.csv(direct[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is the code which does what I want it to do. If there are more elegant solutions, please feel free to point them out.

```
# set the working directory to where the data files are stored
setwd("/foo")

# count the files
files = list.files("/foo")

#create an empty dataframe and name the columns

dataMatrix=data.frame(matrix(c(rep(NA,times=2*length(files))),nrow=length(files)))
colnames(dataMatrix)=c("Postal Code", "Median Income")

# create a for loop to get the information in R2/C1 and R1585/C2 of each data file
# Data is R2/C1 is a string, but is interpreted as a number unless specifically declared a string

for(i in 1:length(files)) {
  getData = read.csv(files[i],header=F)
  dataMatrix[i,1]=toString(getData[2,1])
  dataMatrix[i,2]=(getData[1585,2])
}
```

Thank you to all those who helped me figure this out, especially Nancy.